# Trouble Deploying a Website/Web App on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to deploy a web app on Heroku and it keeps crashing.

After checking the logs, it says it crashed right before `starting process with command 'node app.js'`

After pushing my app to Heroku Git, I clicked on the link and it gave me a `missing script: start`.

I added `"start": "index.js"` to my scripts, replacing the test and `return 1 string`.

Now, I'm getting a different application error.

Here are the logs:

```
2019-04-16T15:55:19.291517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-16T15_55_19_283Z-debug.log
2019-04-16T15:55:22.076257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-16T15:55:24.008573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T15:55:24.034855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T15:55:23.952515+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2019-04-16T15:55:23.958426+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T15:55:23.958664+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-16T15:55:23.958754+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-16T15_55_23_953Z-debug.log
2019-04-16T16:19:04.974643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T16:19:08.471350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-16T16:19:10.946953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T16:19:10.920954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T16:19:10.847576+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2019-04-16T16:19:10.856940+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T16:19:10.862276+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-16T16:19:10.862279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-16T16_19_10_849Z-debug.log
2019-04-16T16:21:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T16:22:14.048093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T16:22:13.644927+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T16:22:13.644927+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 69b62110 by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T16:22:17.615771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-16T16:22:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-04-16T16:22:20.049173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T16:22:20.067122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975525+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975544+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975546+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975548+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975549+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975555+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975557+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-16T16:22:19.975559+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-16T16:25:54.162474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=589c1650-a614-4aae-a8e5-ffb58a523e1e fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T16:25:54.759301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=3c7f8d06-e415-48ae-952d-3968d12db75c fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T16:30:55.410784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T16:30:58.687945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-16T16:31:01.064389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983841+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983863+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983865+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983866+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983868+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983870+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983872+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983873+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983874+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-16T16:31:00.983875+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-16T16:31:01.040784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T16:59:14.705641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T16:59:18.023601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-16T16:59:20.925080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T16:59:20.905853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804107+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804145+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804147+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804149+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804150+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804153+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804155+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804156+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804158+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-16T16:59:20.804159+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-16T17:37:18.987655+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=1fc71b49-e1f4-4e23-b898-9d77035b5e04 fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T17:37:19.514237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=a9886709-5ec0-49da-adfd-0c02d8378903 fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T17:45:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T17:46:08.863208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T17:46:08.459037+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T17:46:08.459037+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9cfd1de3 by user bsautry@ualr.edu
2019-04-16T17:46:12.241604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-16T17:46:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-04-16T17:46:14.898819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T17:46:14.914929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-16T17:46:14.882816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816039+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816072+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816074+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816078+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816080+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816081+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816083+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816084+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-16T17:46:14.816086+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-16T17:46:19.195129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-16T17:46:22.064061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-16T17:46:22.040652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962948+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962978+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962980+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962981+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962983+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962985+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962987+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962989+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962991+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-16T17:46:21.962992+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-16T17:46:22.320545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=a8e86470-1fee-4159-a683-a4437e46ccbc fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T17:46:23.689417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=a7e1403a-3ee9-490f-9446-b4d8150761ee fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T17:49:56.610263+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=fac4cd8f-dfce-4023-bc1d-e27e3297cd59 fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-16T17:49:57.055698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=loveplumbing.herokuapp.com request_id=b431c26e-62c1-42ca-908d-bbe70be171e4 fwd="99.34.148.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I expect it will be some sort of file naming issue.

Comment: `"start": "index.js"` is wrong. You should use `"start": "node index.js"` instead

Comment: changed it, getting the same thing.

Comment: Maybe the machine is not able to resolve absolute paths `/`. Try using relative paths instead (`./` and `../`) , they are more common in Nodejs. Also there are many design patterns in Nodejs execution, so we would need more info: entry point, project file tree, package.json start script...

Comment: Previous comment refers to some `require('/app/app.js')`you have

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to your error messages 
`Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'`

I believe it is trying to find your app.js which is I guess it should be your index.js. What exactly are you using? Angular? If so, check this link as it helped me to understand how to set up an angular project to deploy to heroku.

https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

Comment: im using javascript, ejs, nodejs. so should i change my index.js everywhere to app.js?

Comment: I didnt have a Procfile and my app.json file wasnt setup right plus. i found it easier to use the heroku cli and then just following the heroku docs lol

Comment: ohh ok, yeah, i totally forgot about .json file, nice that heroku cli actually makes things easier!